# Is RedBean ORM able to create unique keys?

Tags: php, sqlite, redbean

I'd like RedBean to create unique keys/indexes when generating the schema. The following code does- opposed to how I understand the documentation- not do this:

R::setup('sqlite:rss_loader.db3');

```
$bean = R::findOne(IMG);
if (!$bean->id) {
    $bean = R::dispense(IMG);
    $bean->setMeta("buildcommand.unique.0", array('url'));
    $bean->url      = 'text';
    R::store($bean);
    $bean->wipe();

    R::freeze(); //no more schema changes!
}
```

What is happening in sqlite ist this:

```
create table img (id integer primary key autoincrement, url)
```

What I was expecting was this:

```
create table img (id integer primary key autoincrement, url text unique)
```

Can this be achieved without write SQL against RedBean?

Comment: Noting that the docs have been fixed about this, see: https://github.com/gabordemooij/redbean/issues/159#issuecomment-5855404

Comment: Thanks damianb- that was _real_ quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Redbean are you using?  It looks like they updated the `buildcommand` in the latest version.  This is what the manual says:

```
$bean->setMeta("buildcommand.unique" , array(array($property1, $property2)));
```

Plugging in what you have:

```
$bean->setMeta("buildcommand.unique" , array(array('url')));
```

If that doesn't work, you may have to read the actual code under the `setMeta` function and see what is actually going on.

To do this on an existing table it is sufficient to "store" an empty bean like this- no data needs to be added to the DB:

```
$bean = R::dispense(IMG);
$bean->setMeta("buildcommand.unique", array(array(...)));
R::store($bean);
```

(Word of warning, if you freeze after doing this, you're not guaranteed to have all your columns)

Comment: Excellent. The trick is to use buildcommand.unique together with the double array.

Comment: Addendum:

To do this on an existing table it is sufficient to "store" an empty bean like this- no data needs to be added to the DB:


    $bean = R::dispense(IMG);
    $bean->setMeta("buildcommand.unique", array(array(...)));
    R::store($bean);